# I can't reach model fields on list

Tags: json, list, flutter, api, drop-down-menu

I did list data from API. I want use list method on list with dropdownmenu but I can't reach field on list. I want to list my data as price increasing or decreasing. How to I solve to this problem?
My list type is RxList.
my list:   RxList productList= [].obs;

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set type to your RxList when declaring it:

```
  RxList<YOUR_TYPE> productList = [].obs;

  productController.productList.sort((a,b)=> //do your sort);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it didn' work? :(

Comment: do you have else suggestions?

Comment: try this too : productController.productList.value.sort((a,b)=> //do your sort);